# How to easily find out which tests fail

Tags: unit-testing, go, testing

I test my code with `go test ./... -v -short`.

Unfortunately, `-v` only prints out each test as it happens, but does not leave a summary of the results at the bottom like in Java. This means that if any test failed somewhere at the top, I have to scroll up and look for the word `FAIL` or search for it in a text editor.

The `-failfast` flag isn't helping either because some of my tests still get printed after the first test failure for some reason.

I don't really care if tests get run after the initial test failure. I just want to be able to easily tell if ***any*** test failed, preferably in just one place (e.g. a summary of how many tests passed or failed, or by seeing a flag if all tests passed or not).

Is there a way to easily tell if there was a test failure because I don't want to accidentally continue coding if I still have test failures.

I'm on Windows 10 64-bit.

***UPDATE:*** Many thanks to @icza for the `findstr` tip. I later realized that I also wanted to see the error descriptions along with the test failures, but did not want to run `go test` twice. This is what I came up with for CMD (does not work on Powershell):

```
go test ./... -v -short > test-results.txt & findstr "FAIL _test" test-results.txt
```

Now `findstr` should report test failures as well as error descriptions. And if you want to see the full test results, simply open `test-results.txt`.

Comment: `go test ./... |grep FAIL` – does this work for you?

Comment: @icza No, `grep` is giving me errors: `grep : The term 'grep' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is 
correct and try again.`

Comment: @icza I just realized grep might need to be installed on Windows. Let me see if I can get this to work...

Comment: `grep` is a unix command. If you don't have it, please tell us what OS do you use.

Comment: @icza My bad, I'm on Windows 10.

Comment: On Windows you may use `findstr` like this: `go test ./... |findstr FAIL`

Comment: I run go test without `-v` and its output is quite short and clear: `go test ./...`. If a unit-test fails it prints enough information to quickly find a test and a line in code. You use verbose output and it is not handy if there are lots of unit-tests

Comment: @Sergei Kurenkov This lessens the output, but failures can still become hard to spot if you have lots of tests. Thanks for the tip, though. :)

Comment: @icza Hmm, `findstr FAIL` seems to do the trick! Please add this as an answer and I'll accept it if no one else can give a better solution in a few days. Thanks!

Comment: Just run it without the `-v` flag?

Comment: @Volker Yeah, Sergei Kurenkov suggested that too, and while it certainly lessens the text output, test failures can still be pretty hard to spot if you have lots and lots of tests.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Failing tests are indicated with `FAIL` in the output. So all you have to do is filter the output for that word.

On Unix systems:

```
go test ./... |grep FAIL
```

On Windows:

```
go test ./... |findstr FAIL
```

Note that this is purely text processing, it doesn't know anything about go tests and their results. This means you might get "false positives" if a test outputs the word `FAIL` even if it succeeds. But in practice, this pretty much does the job you want.

A more sophisticated and more accurate way to achieve this would be to pass `-json` flag to `go test`, so it generates JSON output, which you can process with a program (e.g. written in Go itself). Failing tests are indicated with a JSON object having an `"Action":"fail"` field, e.g.

```
{"Time":"2019-03-01T12:06:21.108544405+01:00","Action":"fail",
 "Package":"some/package","Test":"TestSomething","Elapsed":0.01}
```

And even if you don't want to write a program for this, filtering the JSON output leaves less chance for false positive (filtering for `"Action":"fail"`):

Unix:

```
go test ./... -json |grep '"Action":"fail"'
```

Windows:

```
go test ./... -json |findstr /C:"\"Action\":\"fail\""
```

Comment: If one just needs to know if there is a failure, the return code says it all.

Comment: @leafbebop Yes, but asker specifically stated he wants to know which test(s) failed.

Answer (score 6):

I found it painless to install [gotestsum](https://github.com/gotestyourself/gotestsum) and get the neat summary at the end.

```
go install gotest.tools/gotestsum@latest
gotestsum --format testname # Or dots
```

An alternative, if you only care about the *count* is:

```
go test |grep FAIL |wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

A more structured approach with the `-json` flag and `jq` could list all failing tests like so:

```bash
go test | jq -r 'select(.Action == "fail") | select(.Test | . != null) | .Test'
```

- select where action has failed
- only select outputs for individual tests and filter those without test key
- select test name

Answer (score 0):

This is what works for me:

```
go test | grep -B 1 -A 11 "Error Trace"
```